# Set the special property of multiple controls to the same value

Tags: c#, asp.net

How can I Set the special property of multiple controls to the same value?
For example set the `visible` property of all labels in the form to `true`.
I use this code but labels appear to have null values but they have values.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 foreach ( Label lbl in this.Controls.OfType<Label>()) {
         if (lbl == null) continue;
         lbl.Visible = false;
          } 
}
```

I should mention that I use master page.But I don't want to set the properties of my nested master pages. I want to set the properties of just current ASP page.

Answer (score 1):

You may have some controls within others, so you need to call it recusrively....Here's a similat method I use..............

Notice at the end, I call it from within itself if the Control in question has controls of its' own....

Hope this helps.....

```
private void ClearControls(ControlCollection controlCollection, bool ignoreddlNewOrExisting = false)
{
    foreach (Control control in controlCollection)
    {
        if (ignoreddlNewOrExisting)
        {
            if (control.ID != null)
            {
                if (control.ID.ToUpper() == "DDLNEWOREXISTING")
                {
                    continue;
                }
            }
        }

        if (control is TextBox)
        {
            ((TextBox)control).Text = "";
            ((TextBox)control).Font.Size = 10;
        }
        if (control is DropDownList)
        {
            ((DropDownList)control).SelectedIndex = 0;
            ((DropDownList)control).Font.Size = 10;
        }
        if (control is CheckBox)
        {
            ((CheckBox)control).Checked = false;
        }

        //A bit of recursion
        if (control.Controls != null)
        {
            this.ClearControls(control.Controls, ignoreddlNewOrExisting);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Note that you can use following to avoid this ugly type check.:

```
foreach(Label lbl in this.Controls.OfType<Label>()) 
    lbl.Visible= false;
```

But neither your nor my approach will enumerate all controls *recursively*. Only the controls which are on top of the page. So you won't find labels in nested controls(f.e. in a `GridView`) or which are in the `MasterPage`. Therefore you need a recursive method.

You could use this handy extension method:

```
public static class ControlExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<Control> GetControlsRecursively(this Control parent)
    {
        foreach (Control c in parent.Controls)
        {
            yield return c;

            if (c.HasControls())
            {
                foreach (Control control in c.GetControlsRecursively())
                {
                    yield return control;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then this readable code should hide all labels on the page and in the `MasterPage`:

```
var allLabels = this.GetControlsRecursively()
    .Concat(this.Master.GetControlsRecursively())
    .OfType<Label>();
foreach (Label label in allLabels)
    label.Visible = false;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SetAllLabelValue(this.Controls);
    }
    private void SetAllLabelValue(ControlCollection controls)
    {
        foreach (Control item in controls)
        {
            if (item.HasControls())
            {
                SetAllLabelValue(item.Controls);
            }
            Label lb = item as Label;
            if (lb != null)
            {
                lb.Visible = false;
            }
        }
    }
```